# Problem with passing data in Android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-activity

I want pass data from one activity to second activity. I have update query. This is recovery password. I write email and code in first activity and go to second activity. Them I write password. But when i click last button i second activity i see :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.pawe.aplikacja.DatabaseHelper.updateUser(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

This is first activity.

```
 public void recoverPassword(){
    if (!emptyValidation()) {
        User user = mDatabaseHelper.recoverUser(editTextSaveEmail.getText().toString(), editTextSavePin.getText().toString());
        if (user != null) {

            String  em = editTextSaveEmail.getText().toString();


            Intent intent = new Intent(Recover.this,ChangePassword.class);
            intent.putExtra("email",em);

            startActivity(intent);

            Toast.makeText(Recover.this, "Poprawne dane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Recover.this, "Nie znaleziono", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(Recover.this, "Empty Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is second activity.

```
 private void updateData(){
     if(!emptyValidation()){
            if(!toSame()){

                mDatabaseHelper.updateUser(email,editTextChangePassword.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this,"Zmienione hasło", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this, "Nie pasują do siebie", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
     }else{
         Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this, "Empty Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

in Oncreate is:

```
 email = getIntent().getStringExtra(email);
```

And updateQuery in database.

```
public void updateUser(String email, String password){

    db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD_USER, password);
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL_USER, email);
    String[] whereArgs = {email};
    db.update(TBL_PER,values,COLUMN_EMAIL_USER + " = ?", whereArgs);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialised mDatabaseHelper.

Comment: Initialize in onCreate

Comment: add your onCreate code

Comment: add whole code of second activity

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be initializing `mDatabaseHelper` in your second activity. `onCreate` you initialize the email, but not the `mDatabaseHelper` variable.